# postgrelsql error message : syntax error at or near "ELSE"

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-when

I'm getting an error with the following SQL query

```
SELECT b.mo_id,
        b.ot_id, (select ot_name from object_type where ot_id = b.ot_id
        )ot_name,
        a.obj_id, b.pt_id, b.pt_name, b.data_type, a.prop_value1,
        CASE
        WHEN b.data_type = '2'
        THEN (SELECT code_name FROM site_code WHERE group_seq = b.group_seq AND code_seq = a.prop_value1)
        WHEN b.data_type = '3' THEN TO_CHAR(a.prop_value1,'999,999,999,999,999')
        WHEN b.data_type = '5' AND a.prop_value1 is not null THEN TO_CHAR(to_date(a.prop_value1,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY/MM/DD')
        WHEN b.data_type = '6' THEN TO_CHAR(a.prop_value1,'999,999,999,999,999')
        WHEN b.pt_id = '12003' THEN CONCAT_WS('', SUBSTR(a.prop_value1,0,18) , 
        case when length(a.prop_value1) > 18 then '...' else '' end  ELSE a.prop_value1 
        END prop_value1_view, b.pt_order, b.default_yn, b.list_yn, b.align, b.group_seqFROM 
        (SELECT * FROM property_type WHERE ot_id = #otId# AND list_yn = '1') b LEFT OUTER JOIN
        
        (SELECT * from property where ot_id = #otId# AND obj_id = '') a ON a.ot_id = b.ot_id AND a.pt_id = b.pt_id ORDER BY b.pt_order
```

Comment: A `case` expression only supposed one `else` clause.  I'm voting to close as a typeo.

Answer (score 1):

This case statement is not legitimate:

```
case when length(a.prop_value1) > 18 then '...' else '' end  ELSE a.prop_value1
```

I am not exactly sure what is the objective, but here are options that will fix it.

1. Either this is part of the ongoing case statement (i.e. the previous one) -- In this case, you don't need to write `case` again. It will continue from 'when length(a.prop_value1) > 18 then '...' else '' end  ELSE a.prop_value1 '
2. If you want this to be a separate case statement altogether, you need to end the previous case statement by writing `END` before this case block begins (not to forget writing else part if you intend to.)
3. There are 2 `else` statements one after the other, that's again invalid either one of the else is part of the previous or following block.